# Unable to create an addition Apache Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am following the instructions on the [Apache Kafka website](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). I am currently on Step 6. When I try to start a broker using the command:

```
 sudo bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties
```

I get the following error:

```
0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.
```

This should not be the case since I changed  all instances of 9092 to 9093 in the config/server-1.properties file. Why is it still attempting to use port 9092?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site doesn't explicitly say it, but you need to make sure you uncomment the lines that you have changed.

```
Now edit these new files and set the following properties:

config/server-1.properties:
    broker.id=1
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
    log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1

config/server-2.properties:
    broker.id=2
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
    log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.`

It simply means your port is already in use and again you are trying to run some service on same port.

Check your config files, which you are using for starting brokers, they must be using diff port.